# Shiny downloadHandler returning filename NA when enabled/disabled by the shinyjs package

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

**EDIT**: As per @shosaco's comment below, this is no longer reproducible at least since `shinyjs` 2.0.0

---

Somehow Shiny's `downloadHandler` is incapable of using the user defined filename whenever it was initialized as disabled with the `shinyjs` package.
The downloaded file will end up just being called NA.

Substituting with your own directory and pdf file, will produce a downloaded file called 'NA.pdf' instead of the intended 'report.pdf'.

The following code illustrates the issue:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  
  checkboxInput("checkbox","Check to enable download"),
  
  disabled(downloadButton("report", "Obter relatórios"))
  
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$report = downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.pdf",
    
    content = function(file) {
      file.copy("your dir/your pdf file.pdf", file)      
    },
    
    contentType = "application/pdf"
    
  )
  
  observe({
    
    if (!input$checkbox) {
      
      disable("report")
      
    } else {
      
      enable("report")
      
    }
  })
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

while the following will work normally, producing a downloaded file called report.pdf:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  downloadButton("report", "Obter relatórios")
  
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$report = downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.pdf",
    
    content = function(file) {
      file.copy("your dir/your pdf file.pdf", file)      
    },
    
    contentType = "application/pdf"
    
  )
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I used Edge as the browser to test the shiny app and this is my session info for reference:

```
- Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
 os       Windows >= 8 x64            
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United Kingdom.1252 
 ctype    English_United Kingdom.1252 
 tz       Europe/London               
 date     2019-07-16                  

- Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.0   2017-04-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 bindr         0.1.1   2018-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 bindrcpp    * 0.2.2   2018-03-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 cli           1.0.1   2018-09-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 digest        0.6.18  2018-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 dplyr       * 0.7.8   2018-11-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 glue          1.3.0   2018-07-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 htmltools     0.3.6   2017-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 httpuv        1.4.5   2018-07-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 jsonlite      1.5     2017-06-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 later         0.7.5   2018-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 mime          0.6     2018-10-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 pillar        1.3.0   2018-07-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 pkgconfig     2.0.2   2018-08-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 promises      1.0.1   2018-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 purrr         0.2.5   2018-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 R6            2.3.0   2018-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 Rcpp          1.0.0   2018-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 rlang         0.3.0.1 2018-10-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 RODBC       * 1.3-15  2017-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 rstudioapi    0.8     2018-10-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 shiny       * 1.2.0   2018-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 shinyjs     * 1.0     2018-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 shinyTree   * 0.2.6   2018-10-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 tibble        1.4.2   2018-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 tidyselect    0.2.5   2018-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 xtable        1.8-3   2018-08-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 yaml          2.2.0   2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 zip         * 2.0.3   2019-07-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
```

Comment: I have the same issue, it may be something to report to `shinyjs` developers

Comment: Note: not reproducible with shinyjs 2.0.0